# Как правильно вывести дату и время?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

в переменной message.date лежит значение, если его вывести в шаблон то выдаст = `2022-04-21 10:39:58.000000+0300`
Я хочу чтобы выводило только 10:39
Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя `getHours` и `getMinutes`

```js
let date = new Date();
let time = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
console.log(time);
```

А если у вас дата в виде строки то так

```js
let string = '2022-04-21 10:39:58.000000+0300';
let date = new Date(string);
let time = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
console.log(time);
```